# SQL Server : how many days each item was in each state

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

Given a table that stores every revision for every item.

For example:

```
+--------+----------+---------------+--------+---------------------+
| ItemId | Revision | PreviousState | State  |     DateChanged     |
+--------+----------+---------------+--------+---------------------+
|      1 |        1 | NULL          | New    | 2014-11-13 10:00:00 |
|      1 |        2 | New           | Active | 2014-11-15 10:00:00 |
|      1 |        3 | Active        | New    | 2014-11-17 10:00:00 |
|      1 |        4 | New           | Active | 2014-11-19 10:00:00 |
|      1 |        5 | New           | Active | 2014-11-20 10:00:00 |
|      1 |        6 | Active        | Closed | 2014-11-22 10:00:00 |
|      2 |        1 | NULL          | New    | 2014-11-13 10:00:00 |
|      2 |        2 | New           | Active | 2014-11-16 10:00:00 |
|      2 |        3 | Active        | Closed | 2014-11-17 10:00:00 |
|      2 |        4 | Closed        | Active | 2014-11-19 10:00:00 |
|      2 |        5 | Active        | Closed | 2014-11-21 10:00:00 |
+--------+----------+---------------+--------+---------------------+
```

I need to calculate how many days each item was in each state (except 'Close').

Result should be like this:

```
+--------+-----+--------+
| ItemId | New | Active |
+--------+-----+--------+
|      1 |   4 |      5 |
|      2 |   3 |      3 |
+--------+-----+--------+
```

I tried to use two approaches - `GROUP BY` and nested cursors.

Using cursors (especially nested cursors) is a bad practice. And the are very slow.

`GROUP BY` also won't work because there is no strict order of states (New -> Active -> Closed). It could be chaotic New -> Active -> Closed -> Active -> Closed -> New -> Closed.

I don't see any other way to calculate it without iterating all the records and comparing states.

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems like a stored procedure or script (like php) task to me

Comment: fwiw, I would try my hardest to avoid NULL.  It makes all sorts of criteria unnecessarily complex because NULL only really works with IS NULL and IS NOT NULL, by design.  You could N/A on PreviousState for a NEW for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the same results you're asking for, in a slightly different format (but you can easily find `PIVOT` solutions if you need the exact same result set):

```
declare @t table (ItemId int,Revision int,State varchar(19),DateChanged datetime2)
insert into @t(ItemId,Revision,State,DateChanged) values
(1,1,'New',   '2014-11-13T10:00:00'),
(1,2,'Active','2014-11-15T10:00:00'),
(1,3,'New',   '2014-11-17T10:00:00'),
(1,4,'Active','2014-11-19T10:00:00'),
(1,5,'Active','2014-11-20T10:00:00'),
(1,6,'Closed','2014-11-22T10:00:00'),
(2,1,'New',   '2014-11-13T10:00:00'),
(2,2,'Active','2014-11-16T10:00:00'),
(2,3,'Closed','2014-11-17T10:00:00'),
(2,4,'Active','2014-11-19T10:00:00'),
(2,5,'Closed','2014-11-21T10:00:00')

;With Joined as (
    select t1.ItemId,t1.State,DATEDIFF(day,t1.DateChanged,t2.DateChanged) as Days
    from
        @t t1
            inner join
        @t t2
            on
                t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId and
                t1.Revision = t2.Revision -1
    )
select ItemId,State,SUM(Days)
from Joined
where State <> 'Closed'
group by ItemId,State
```

Result:

```
ItemId      State               
----------- ------------------- -----------
1           Active              5
1           New                 4
2           Active              3
2           New                 3
```

Note that I'm ignoring the `PreviousState` column from your question and am instead constructing `Joined` because what really matters is *when* the **next** state came into effect.

---

Issues not dealt with because you've not described them in your question: 1) What to do if the current final state isn't `Closed` - i.e. do we ignore that, or count until today?, and 2) What to do if the time of day for each `DateChanged` isn't the same - do we have to handle partial days?

Comment: CTE's are so much cleaner than the old sub queries, I definitely need to use them more often, just for the simple fact that they are so much cleaner to read and debug.  -- Nice clean code

Comment: 1) What to do if the current final state isn't Closed - i.e. do we ignore that, or count until today? -- Final state will always be closed. I filter all not closed items.

Comment: 2) What to do if the time of day for each DateChanged isn't the same - do we have to handle partial days? -- Yes. As far as I know DATEDIFF() should handle this situation. Thanks.

Comment: @GhostMaster - `DATEDIFF` always returns integers - so if you ask for the difference between 10am today and 10pm, the answer is 0. Conversely, the difference between 10pm today and 10am tomorrow is 1. And it measures transitions - the difference between 11.59pm tonight and 00.01am tomorrow is also 1. If you need to deal with partial days that accumlate, you might want to do the `DATEDIFF`s in hours (or minutes or seconds) and then divide the result appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like the CTE from [Damien_The_Unbeliever], I need to use them more often. Using inner joins I basically do the same thing the add a pivot wrapper around the results to get what you are looking for: (replace @t for your real table name)

```
SELECT ItemId , [New],[Active]
FROM
(
SELECT 
    ItemId , LASTSTATE,  DATEDIFF(D, LASTDATE, DateChanged) AS D 
FROM 
    @T AS T 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            ItemId as ItemLink, 
            Revision + 1 AS RevLink , 
            DateChanged AS LASTDATE , 
            State AS LASTSTATE from @t
        ) AS L ON T.ItemId = L.ItemLink AND T.Revision = L.RevLink
) AS P PIVOT ( SUM(D) FOR LASTSTATE IN ([New],[Active],[Closed])) AS DATA
```