# How many Days each item was in each State, the full value of the period

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This post is really similar to my question:
[SQL Server : how many days each item was in each state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151677/sql-server-how-many-days-each-item-was-in-each-state)

but I dont have the column **Revision** to see wich is the previous state, and also I want to get the full time of a status, I b

....

I'm want to get how long one item has been in one status in general, my table look like this:

```
    ID                                      DATE                     STATUS
    3D56B7B1-FCB3-4897-BAEB-004796E0DC8D    2016-04-05 11:30:00.000  1
    3D56B7B1-FCB3-4897-BAEB-004796E0DC8D    2016-04-08 11:30:00.000  13
    274C5DA9-9C38-4A54-A697-009933BB7B7F    2016-04-29 08:00:00.000  5
    274C5DA9-9C38-4A54-A697-009933BB7B7F    2016-05-04 08:00:00.000  4
    A70A66DC-9D9E-49BE-93CF-00F9E3E06CE2    2016-04-14 07:50:00.000  1
    A70A66DC-9D9E-49BE-93CF-00F9E3E06CE2    2016-04-21 14:00:00.000  2
    A70A66DC-9D9E-49BE-93CF-00F9E3E06CE2    2016-04-23 12:15:00.000  3
    A70A66DC-9D9E-49BE-93CF-00F9E3E06CE2    2016-04-23 16:15:00.000  1
    BF122AE1-CB39-4967-8F37-012DC55E92A7    2016-04-05 10:30:00.000  1
    BF122AE1-CB39-4967-8F37-012DC55E92A7    2016-04-20 17:00:00.000  5
```

I want to get this

```
Column 1 : ID Column 2 : Status Column 3 : Time with the status
```

> Column 3 : Time with the status
>    = NextDate - PreviosDate + 1

- if is the last Status, is count as 1
- if is more than one Status on the same day, I get the Last one (u can say that only mather the last Status of the day)
- by ID, Status must be unique

I should look like this:

```
ID                                      STATUS      TIME
3D56B7B1-FCB3-4897-BAEB-004796E0DC8D    1           3
3D56B7B1-FCB3-4897-BAEB-004796E0DC8D    13          1
274C5DA9-9C38-4A54-A697-009933BB7B7F    5           5
274C5DA9-9C38-4A54-A697-009933BB7B7F    4           1
A70A66DC-9D9E-49BE-93CF-00F9E3E06CE2    1           8
A70A66DC-9D9E-49BE-93CF-00F9E3E06CE2    2           2   
BF122AE1-CB39-4967-8F37-012DC55E92A7    1           15
BF122AE1-CB39-4967-8F37-012DC55E92A     5           1
```

Comment: have you tried using lead() or lag()?

Comment: no se que es eso ..

Comment: No conozco esos terminos - I dont know what that is? I really need to resolve that and I dont know when I'll be able to access to internet again since I live in Cuba, I have alredy a solution but is using Linq to Sql and is really slow so I need to improve that.

Comment: Try `SELECT ID, Status, Date, LEAD(DATE ,1) over (partition by id order by date) FROM table` I think with that in hand you should be able to put together a solution

Comment: Thank, normally I just need some clue ...

Comment: SELECT 
 ID,
 STATE,
 DATE,
 LEAD(DATE,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) LeadValue,
 isnull(DATEDIFF(dayofyear,  DATE,
 LEAD(DATE,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID)), 1) DIF_BY_LEAD
FROM TABLENAME s
WHERE ID = 'A70A66DC-9D9E-49BE-93CF-00F9E3E06CE2'
ORDER BY ID, DATE ...... it work

Comment: @ConradFrix thank so much, it actually work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ConradFrix comments, this is how works ..

```
WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT
        ID,
        STATUS, 
        DATE, 
        LEAD(DATE, 1) over (partition by ID order by DATE) LEAD,
        ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAYOFYEAR,  DATE,
        LEAD(DATE, 1) over (partition by ID order by DATE)), 1)  DIF_BY_LEAD
        FROM TABLE_NAME
    )
    SELECT ID, STATUS, SUM(DIF_BY_LEAD) AS TIME_STATUS 
    FROM CTE GROUP BY ID, STATUS
    ORDER BY ID, STATUS
```